# How to find the unix 'host' from the aws 'Endpoint'

Tags: amazon-web-services, pg-dump

I'm looking for the 'host' of an aws database server to use in this configuration option:

```
-h host
--host=host

Specifies the host name of the machine on which the server is running.
If the value begins with a slash, it is used as the directory for the
Unix domain socket. The default is taken from the PGHOST environment
variable, if set, else a Unix domain socket connection is attempted.
```

But all I can find is this 'Endpoint':

```
Endpoint: foobar.ab12cd34ef.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

Is that related?  Is there any way to extract the 'host' from the 'Endpoint'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the endpoint as your host, it's what you should be using to connect to RDS. 5432 is the port it's running on.

RDS provides you an endpoint because by design it can have multiple backend "hosts" (database instances) serving data such as in a multi-AZ environment. By providing you with the endpoint you don't have to change your connection string when your master fails and the slave is promoted to master, etc.